# java -http post request from port 80 is not working

Tags: java

I have deployed an paypal ipn service on my local machine on port 80.From this ipn service i am hitting another service which on asp.net(iis),but http post data is getting being truncated on reaching the iis server.And if i do the the same from another port except 80,it is working without any issue.I am not getting ,why my http post request data is not reaching there just because of using port 80.

Comment: I would take a look at any firewalls (or similar) which may exist between the hosts.  The port number should be arbitrary in terms of how the data is actually sent; it seems more likely it's being snipped in transit.